# Save multiple input from drop down list to database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to yii and i am unable to store multiple selected data to database.
there are three tables in my database 'product' 'seller' and 'productseller' with many to many relationship. product table contain pro_name and pro_id fields, seller table has sel_id and sel_name fields and productseller table has pro_id and sel_id fielsd. 
What i am doing is to choose seller name and related multiple products from from dropdown list and then store them in productseller table.

My view:

```
    <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Select Seller'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'sel_id', 
            CHtml::listData(Seller::model()->findAll(), 'sel_id', 'sel_name')); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'sel_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Choose Products'); ?>
            <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'maincat_id'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'pro_id', 
CHtml::listData(Product::model()->findAll(), 'pro_id', 'pro_name'),
            array('multiple'=>'multiple', 'size'=>5)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'maincat_id'); ?>
    </div>
```

My seller controller

```
$model = new ProductSeller;     
            $this->render('insertItems', array('model'=>$model));
            if(isset($_POST['ProductSeller']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['ProductSeller'];
                    if($model->save())

                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model-   >sel_id));
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->pro_id));

            }
```

Seller Model

```
public function relations()
    {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                    'productSellers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductSeller', 'sel_id'),
            );
    }
```

Product Model

```
  public function relations()
    {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                    'productSellers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductSeller', 'pro_id'),
            );
    }
```

ProductSeller Model

```
public function relations()
    {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                    'pro' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'pro_id'),
                    'sel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Seller', 'sel_id'),
            );
    }
```

What steps should i follow to save pro_id and sel_id to database?
Thanks 
0

Answer (score 1):

With minumum changes your action should looks like:

```
$model = new ProductSeller;
if(isset($_POST['ProductSeller'])){
  $is_valid = true;
  $list = array();
  foreach( $_POST['ProductSeller']['pro_id'] as $pro_id ) {
    $list[ $pro_id ] = new ProductSeller;
    $list[ $pro_id ]->setAttributes(array(
      'sel_id' => $_POST['ProductSeller']['sel_id'],
      'pro_id' => $pro_id,
    ));
    $is_valid = $list[ $pro_id ]->validate() && $is_valid;
  }

  if ( $is_valid ) {
    foreach( $list as $m ) {
      $m->save(false);
    ));
    $this->redirect(/*...*/);
  }
}
$this->render('insertItems',array('model'=>$model));
```

Comment: Another moment. It's wrong to use model attribute both for store array and int values. Add another attribute `protected $pro_ids = array()` and methods `public function setProIds( $value ) { $this->pro_ids = $value; }` and `public function getProIds( $value ){ return $this->pro_ids; }`